# How do I generate all combinations of integers in java when placement is restricted?

Tags: java, integer, permutation, combinations

I need to generate permutations over a set of integers.

However the placement of the numbers matter.

In position 0, the range is from 0-2. In position 1, the range is from 0-3. In position 2, the range is from 0-1.

So the answer would be:

000
001
010
011
020
021
030
031

100
101
110
111
120
121
130
131

200
201
210
211
220
221
230
231

Comment: build yourself some `for` loop and iterate through the numbers

Comment: could you be more precise about the range please? With range you mean *including interval* like: [0,2][0,3][0,1] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test x = new Test();
        x.generatePermutations(2, 3, 1);
    }

    private void generatePermutations(int intervalOne, int intervalTwo,
            int intervalThree) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= intervalOne; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= intervalTwo; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k <= intervalThree; k++) {
                    System.out.print(i + "" + j + "" + k + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I think this will do an array of any number of intervals: (You have to check its correctness though:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test x = new Test();
        int[] intervals = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        x.generatePermutations(intervals);
    }

    private void generatePermutations(int[] intervals) {
        generatePermutations(intervals, 0, "");
    }

    private void generatePermutations(int[] intervals, int intpos,
            String lastPerm) {

        if (intpos == intervals.length)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i <= intervals[intpos]; i++) {
            if (intpos == intervals.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(lastPerm + i + " ");
            }
            generatePermutations(intervals, intpos + 1, lastPerm + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: got any tips for when there is a variable number of positions instead of just 3 positions?

Comment: Added a code snippet for usage with an array that could have various number of intervals.

Answer (score 1):

This solution can be solved with three nested loops as shown in the previous solution. But, how about N numbers? We can also solve that problem without using recursion. Here is a simple solution, where we iterate each possible value one by one.

We start from minimum values for each number and continuously increase the rightmost number by one to find new permutations. Just like a counter (e.g., binary or decimal), we increase the rightmost number until it reaches its maximum value. When it hits it maximum value, we reset that number to its minimum value and increase the number of its left. We repeat this process until there is no need to move to the left number.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generatePermutations(new int[][]{{0,2}, {0,3}, {0,1}});
    }

    /**
     * Generates all possible permutations for given ranges
     * @param ranges 2D array of ranges (min and max, inclusive) for each position,
     *               e.g., {{0,2}, {0,3}, {0,1}} denotes that first position has a
     *               range between 0 and 2, inclusive.
     */
    private static void generatePermutations(int[][] ranges) {
        //Array that holds a single permutation, e.g., {0,1,1}
        int permutation[] = new int[ranges.length];

        //Initialize permutation array with the min values for each range
        for (int i = 0; i < permutation.length; i++) {
            permutation[i] = ranges[i][0];
        }

        //Print all possible permutations
        do {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation));
        } while (increaseRightMostPosition(ranges, permutation));
    }

    /**
     * Increases the right most position of permutation array to find a new permutation.
     * Method does not return the new permutation array, since input array is modified.
     *
     * @param ranges ranges array given in generatePermutations method
     * @param permutation permutation array to be increased
     * @return false when all possible permutations are found
     */
    private static boolean increaseRightMostPosition(int[][] ranges, int[] permutation) {
        /*
            Increases the right-most number of the permutation array. If that number exceeds
            its max value, reset it with its min value, and increase the number left of it.
            Repeat this process, until finding a valid permutation.
         */
        for (int i = permutation.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            permutation[i]++;
            if (permutation[i] > ranges[i][1]) {
                permutation[i] = ranges[i][0];
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```